# How to divide scrollview layout into multiple views of fixed size for creating multiple pages PDF in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, pdf-generation

I have a ScrollView layout, and under that, I have multiple types of views(For example Text View, Recycler view, etc.), now I have to create a pdf of that layout. My current method takes the list of layout views to create multiple pages in PDF. Now I have only a single view which is ScrollView. Now how can I break this ScrollView in multiple fixed-size views for A4 size pages for the PDF?

Or there is any library which automatically manages this and creates PDF file efficiently and manages content cropping also. For example, if the next line can not fit in the current page then it should automatically be shifted to the next page. (Like below screenshot)

I want this type of result.

[image]

Comment: looking for the solution in iOS, However you need to create the scrollview and capture the ui and scroll the view programmatically capture the screen that way you can proceed , In my case there were repeated header and footer so also app itself was in landscape mode and client wanted A4 size printable PDF, now god save me